# Combine objects in array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like follows

0: {bill_no: '0000633', test_code: '1', analyzer_code: '2'}

1: {bill_no: '0000633', test_code: '2', analyzer_code: '2'}

2: {bill_no: '0000633', test_code: '28', analyzer_code: '3'}

3: {bill_no: '0000633', test_code: '254', analyzer_code: '2'}

I want to combine those objects to get the following result (join the objects based on same analyzer_code).

0: {bill_no: '0000633', test_code: '1,2,254', analyzer_code: '2'}

1: {bill_no: '0000633', test_code: '28', analyzer_code: '3'}

How can I achieve this in Javascript?

Edit: bill_no will be same in the every object

Comment: If the array contains 2 object with the same `analyser_code` but different `bill_no`, how the objects should be merged?

Comment: what goes wrong?

Comment: @Raffaele bill_no will be same in the array everytime. The data is retrived by using the bill_no. So bill_no will be same all the time

Comment: @NinaScholz No idea about concatinating the test_code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you want to group by `bill_no` and `analyzer_code`.

One way is to use `reduce` and collect groups by a key that is the combination of `bill_no` and `analyzer_code` properties. I'll use `JSON.stringify` to create such a key:

```js
let data = [
  {bill_no: '0000633', test_code: '1', analyzer_code: '2'},
  {bill_no: '0000633', test_code: '2', analyzer_code: '2'},
  {bill_no: '0000633', test_code: '28', analyzer_code: '3'},
  {bill_no: '0000633', test_code: '254', analyzer_code: '2'}
];

let result = Object.values(
    data.reduce((acc, {bill_no, test_code, analyzer_code}) => {
        let key = JSON.stringify([bill_no, analyzer_code]);
        if (acc[key]) acc[key].test_code += "," + test_code
        else acc[key] = {bill_no, test_code, analyzer_code};
        return acc;
    }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```